# How do I get the content of <a href> when I know only the name of the next tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to get the content of `a href` using JavaScript (not jQuery). In the example I show below it is string `some-link-here`.

I have tried various combinations of `document.querySelector` such as

`document.querySelector("h2").getElementsByTagName("a")[0=].previous.Sibling.textContent`

but I cannot the string I want.

```
<td align='center' rowspan=2 valign='top'><a href='some-link-here'><h2>DOWNLOAD</h2>
```

Comment: So the h2 is inside the anchor? Can you give us a better chunk of HTML?

Comment: @arhak Why? it is not invalid.

Comment: Having an `h2` inside an anchor is perfectly valid HTML 5.

Comment: @arhak https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a Any modern browser should be 100% fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the value of the `href`:

```
document.querySelector('h2').parentElement.getAttribute('href')
```

The anchor (A) is the parent element of the header (H2) element.

---

Based on your comment, this will change the header's text content to match its parent's href:

```
var h2 = document.querySelector('h2');
h2.textContent = h2.parentElement.getAttribute('href')
```

Comment: I tried your code but it seems that it shows `DOWNLOAD` instead of the link. Please have a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/bwsr2Lsy/1/

Comment: I may have misunderstood your original post.  See my update, along with this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/bwsr2Lsy/4

Comment: Rick, perfect thanks! And also thanks for a quick reply since I wasn't probably clear enought in my first post.

Answer (score 1):

If you know where exactly after how many anchor() tag your desirable tag is present, then you can use below code by just replacing array index (0 here)

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute("href")
```

Otherwise you can use below code if you only know the child tag.

```
document.querySelector('h2').parentElement.getAttribute("href")
```

According to your requirement, if [H2] tag is not a child of [A] and just a next tag, you should try below code.

```
document.querySelector('h2').previousElementSibling.href
```

Comment: so you select the first link on the page?

Comment: yes. The first code will select first link on the page. You can add a particular id to your <a> tag and you can use `document.getElementById("yourId").getAttribute("href")` which is super easy, if possible.

Comment: Same comment as to Rick: I tried your code but it seems that it shows DOWNLOAD instead of the link. Please have a look at: jsfiddle.net/bwsr2Lsy/1

Comment: Where is your anchor tag ending. Is [H2] tag is a parent tag to [A] or just a next tag to [A] ??

Comment: I have no idea.The site I took the code from in now offline.

Comment: @menteith, updated my answer, Please check once and help me to earn points. Thank you :)

Comment: @Jyotirmay Your second solution works fine! I've upvoted your answer.